# Android NoClassDefFoundError when run from Eclipse

Tags: java, android, maven, noclassdeffounderror

So I have an app that has previously worked perfectly in Eclipse.

Since I have converted to Maven, I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError` when I try to start a particular activity (`SliderMenuActivity`).

The strange thing is that the app will start and load the main activity (`StartActivity`) which is the same package. Note that both activities are included in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

It seems that the offending piece of code is:

```
Intent intSliderActivity = new Intent(StartActivity.this, SliderMenuActivity.class);
```

Just wondering does the change to the `src` folder have anything to do with this?

I have also changed the source folder to look like `src/main/java/com/conor/etc` and updated the build path.

Any ideas on how to solve?

For reference, here is the stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(25063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(25063): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.my_app.android.app.SliderMenuActivity
at com.my_app.android.app.StartActivity$6.my_appApiCallback(StartActivity.java:261)
at com.my_app.android.app.my_app_user_api.my_appApiTask.onPostExecute(my_appApiTask.java:129)
at com.my_app.android.app.my_app_user_api.my_appApiTask.onPostExecute(my_appApiTask.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please clean your project

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html   did you look at before ?

Comment: Hi Guys, yes I have tried both to no avail.

Comment: be clear first of all.read my comment in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

declare your class in manifest file with package name like

```
<activity android:name="com.example.SliderMenuActivity">
```

Comment: My questions states that I have already defined both activities in manifest!

Comment: you didn't wrote that you have defined with package name or without.

Comment: you logcat shows that you have defined your activity's package as 
com.my_app.android.app.SliderMenuActivity and your class is in andother package src/main/java/com/conor/etc as you wrote.kindly review your question.

Comment: My apologies, that was bady changed. Changed the name of my app before posting question. I was just giving examples for src/main/java/com/conor/etc

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not build success LeftMenuSide library. Please try to build again

Comment: Why do you think that? What library are you referring to? I don't use a library "LeftMenuSide".

Comment: I think you use external library project, but not build success so cause NoClassDefFoundError. Can you show the line #261 of StartActivity.java?